MongoDB aggregation pipeline: pagination is not working as expected with id cursor and text index
I'm making an aggregation query to my MongoDB using a text index, I implemented a pagination system but it's not working as expected
At first, I thought it was related to the other sort field, but it seems like the id alone is not working properly.
Also, I'm pretty sure a pagination system is possible with multiple sort parameter
So, here is the aggregation pipeline (it's in JavaScript)
pipeline:           [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $text: { $search: `"${key}"` },
                                ...(query.previousId ? { _id: { $gt: query.previousId } } : {}),
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            $sort: {
                                _id: 1,
                                created_t: -1,
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            $limit: 10,
                        },
                    ],

It's using the text index, and I want my pagination to work using the previous last id
It's "working", but when I use the previousId, I can see some of the previous result coming in the next result, and I don't know how to fix this with mongo
Does someone have an idea about how mongo index and sorting work and how I can use it properly with my id ?
